# How to parse a json string response using Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, parsing, delphi-xe

I have a rest server returning the next json string:

```
response:='{"result":["[{\"email\":\"XXX@gmail.com\",\"regid\":\"12312312312312312313213w\"},{\"email\":\"YYYY@gmail.com\",\"regid\":\"AAAAAAA\"}]"]}';
```

I´d like to parse the response to get a list of all `email` and `regid` items.

I have tried the next code but I am getting an AV at  `(TJSONPair(LItem).JsonString.Value='email')`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Luiz

```
var
  LResult:TJSONArray;
  LJsonresponse:TJSONObject;
  i:integer;
  LItem,jv:TJsonValue;
  email,regid:string;

      LJsonresponse:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response),0) as TJSONObject;
      LResult:=(LJsonresponse.GetValue('result') as TJSONArray);
      jv:=TJSONArray(LResult.Get(0));
      for LItem in TJSONArray(jv) do begin
         if (TJSONPair(LItem).JsonString.Value='email') then begin
           email:=TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value;
         end;
         if (TJSONPair(LItem).JsonString.Value='regid') then begin
           regid:=TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value;
         end;
      end;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problems start here:

```
jv := TJSONArray(LResult.Get(0));
```

The problem is that `LResult.Get(0)` does not return an instance of `TJSONArray`. In fact it returns an instance of `TJSONString`. That string has value:

```
'[{"email":"XXX@gmail.com","regid":"12312312312312312313213w"},{"email":"YYYY@gmail.com","regid":"AAAAAAA"}]'
```

It looks like you are going to need to parse this string as JSON to extract what you need. Here is some gnarly code that does that. Please excuse its quality because I have no experience at all with the Delphi JSON parser.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, JSON;

const
  response =
    '{"result":["[{\"email\":\"XXX@gmail.com\",\"regid\":\"12312312312312312313213w\"},'+
    '{\"email\":\"YYYY@gmail.com\",\"regid\":\"AAAAAAA\"}]"]}';

procedure Main;
var
  LResult: TJSONArray;
  LJsonResponse: TJSONObject;
  ja: TJSONArray;
  jv: TJSONValue;
begin
  LJsonResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(response) as TJSONObject;
  LResult := LJsonResponse.GetValue('result') as TJSONArray;
  ja := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(LResult.Items[0].Value) as TJSONArray;
  for jv in ja do begin
    Writeln(jv.GetValue<string>('email'));
    Writeln(jv.GetValue<string>('regid'));
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

The big lesson here is to stop using unchecked type casts. Using such casts is asking for trouble. When your data does not match your code, you get unhelpful error messages.

Comment: Amazing, Mr David. It´s working very well.  Thank you.